# Changing background color of button in React-Native-Material-Design module

Tags: reactjs, native

I've been trying to change the background color of a button using this module "react-native-material-desing". In the documentation ("https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design/blob/master/lib/Button.js") they say you have to override the background color and i think im doing it right but for some reason it doesn't work, no errors or nothing simply the color stays default.

heres my button code inside the render.

```js
    <Button 
     onPress={this.gotoNext.bind(this)}
     text='Login' 
     theme = 'dark'
     textColor  = 'white'
     raised={true} 
     overrides={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
    />
```

Any idea or solution? thanks :)

Comment: Just for poops and giggles, have you tried `#F00`?

Comment: Yee mb thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to change background color in react-native-material-design.
Please use `raised=true` other wise background color is not override.

```
<Button value="submit"
             raised={true}
             backgroundColor='#F00'
             onPress={//your onPress event here}
             text="Submit"/>
```

Comment: in iOS, the background color has no effect at all.